# saving NSMutableArrays to pList

Tags: xcode, plist

i'm trying to store a NSMutableArray into a pList but when i check my data.pList , there isn't any values inside. Any idea why?

```
-(void)run
{
Global *myGlobal = [Global sharedGlobal];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];

NSMutableDictionary *category = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableDictionary *totalCategory = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
for (int i = 0 ; i < [myGlobal.categoryArray count];i++){
    Category * c = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:i];

    [category setObject:c.name forKey:@"category"];

    [totalCategory setObject:category forKey:@"allCategory"];

    NSMutableDictionary *stock = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [stock writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
if( totalCategory==nil ){
    NSLog(@"failed to retrieve dictionary from disk");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These two lines don't make sense.  The first line reads a dictionary from `path` into `stock`, the second line writes it back out.  Nothing was added to `stock`.

```
NSMutableDictionary *stock = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
[stock writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: if i do not include the line [writeToFile] then it wont store my dictionary/array into the pList isn't it?

Comment: true, but you need to put something into `stock` or writeToFile will store nothing.

Answer (score 0):

When saving to the pList, you should try to make it like this.

```
[totalCategory writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

this is an example how it works fine

```
+ (void) saveParams:(int)kotuc one:(NSNumber*)one two:(NSNumber*)two three:(NSNumber*)three four:(NSNumber*)four five:(NSNumber*)five six:(NSNumber*)six seven:(NSNumber*)seven eight:(NSArray*)eight{

    NSString *path = [self getNSPath];
    NSDictionary* dw = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSMutableDictionary* dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSArray *keys = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", @"four", @"five", @"six",@"seven", @"eight",nil] retain];
    NSArray *objects = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nil] retain];


    NSMutableDictionary *subDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:(NSArray *)objects forKeys:(NSArray *)keys];


    ////save old
    [dict setDictionary:dw];
    ////save new
    [dict setObject:subDict forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", kotuc]];    // 
    //write to file
    [dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];


    [dw release];
    [dict release];
    [subDict release];
    [keys release];
    [objects release];
}
```

Comment: the problem is even though i'm able to run this line w/o much problem but when i check my data.plist , there isn't any values in it.

Comment: Is totalCategory fulfill with data? The strange thing about your code is, that you want to pick data in loop, but you set a static key (category or allCategory), keys in any dictionary suppose to be unique. This way you can get only on record per dictionary, so no loop is needed.

Comment: yeah totalCategory have 7different categories in it , and i want to store 7 of them into the pList. Is there any tutorial that have excellent explanation about pList? most of them just have codes on how to initiate paths to your plist e.g the documentDirectory and stuff

Comment: I haven't seen any tutorial about pList, but your code looks good regarding pList, except the line with stock. If you do it this way, you pick data already saved in path a then you write it back to the path, so it do nothing. You need to write totalCategory to the path as I suggested.